# jenkins codesign : Frameworks/OpenSSL.framework: errSecInternalComponent - Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, command-line, keychain, cicd

Im trying to build ci/cd ios App with jenkins using ec2 mac instance of AWS.
I set up all my certificates/private key using the command

`security import ./myfile.p12` or `security add-certificate`

I also added my Provisionning Profile successfully.

The build is running but at the final step Im getting an error during the codesign --force step. I read a lot of question over there but non of the solution provided worked for me..

[Error details of the Build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToQj0.jpg)

For info: when I run `security default-keychain` command, I get as the default keychain : /Library/Keychains/System.keychain

And running :
`security find-identity -v -p codesigning /Library/Keychains/System.keychain`
gaves me result like:

1. XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX "iPhone Distribution: corp (Land) LTD."
2. XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX "iPhone Developer: John Doe (XXXXX)"

I already tried to lock/unlock my keychain without success..

Is anyone has an idea how to resolve this issue please ?

Answer (score 0):

After a weeks of research, I just deleted all my certificates form the System.keychain (the corp one and the two of Apple authority - those who expire in 2023 and 2030 ) and reinstall them !
This made the job at the end